# Modifying values of XML nodes with XML DML in SQL queries

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, dml

I am trying to modify node values within an XML database field using XML DML within a SQL query.

Say my table field has xml something like this:-

```
<ContentTree>
<ContentObject>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <Order>999</Order>
</ContentObject>
<ContentObject >
  <Id>5</Id>
  <Order>999</Order>
</ContentObject>
<ContentObject >
  <Id>3</Id>
  <Order>999</Order>
</ContentObject>
</ContentTree>
```

Is there a way I can use XML DML within a SQL query to modify the Order value based on the Id value, e.g.
Something like:-

```
If  /ContentTree/ContentObject/Id /text()[1] ="5" 

Then 

Replace value of  /ContentTree/ContentObject/Order/text()[1]
with ("2")
```

My real data is very long and it is not easy to calculate the index numbers of the ContentObjects, so I don't want to have to identify the specifc Order node via its ContentObject index number.

Many thanks.

Comment: I advice you to select it in table, update values and save in xml again. I think, it's more simple.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example:

```
DECLARE  @table TABLE (value XML)

INSERT INTO @table
(
    [value]
)
VALUES
(
  N'<ContentTree>
<ContentObject>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <Order>999</Order>
</ContentObject>
<ContentObject>
  <Id>5</Id>
  <Order>999</Order>
</ContentObject>
<ContentObject >
  <Id>3</Id>
  <Order>999</Order>
</ContentObject>
</ContentTree>'
)

UPDATE @table
SET
    [value].modify('replace value of (/ContentTree/ContentObject/Id[text()="5"]/../Order/text())[1] with "5"')

SELECT *
FROM @table t
```